# building image with Ansible-builder and need to install python36 and python3-ldap

Tags: automation, ansible

building image with Ansible-builder and need to install python36 and python3-ldap into the image but I'm not sure where to add python36 and python3-ldap to the requirements.txt or bindep.txt

Can someone with Ansible-builder experience provide direction?
below is my execution-enviroment.yml file

```
version: 1
build_arg_defaults:
  EE_BASE_IMAGE: 'privatehub/ee-minimal-rhel'
  EE_BUILDER_IMAGE: 'privatehub/ansible-builder-rhel'
dependencies:
  galaxy: requirements.yml
  python: requirements.txt
  system: bindep.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The python modules get placed on the requirements.txt file and the python36 system file gets placed on the bindep.txt file

Thanks for all those who looked!